# QGraphicsScene and fitInView() not scaling correctly despite using itemsBoundingRect()

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyqt, pyqt5

I include the entire code - the problem is (I believe!) with the function adjust_gx on line 145-153..

The problem is that the QGraphicsScene is NOT scaling correctly to the QGraphicsView.  I'm hoping to use a set of standard shapes and fill a grid, which resizes either according to the window, or according to the cell size value. - but it's rendering very small, or resizes in a miserable manner.

I have found ways of scaling it up, but then it goes out of sync completely when 'size' is varied (ranging between 16 and 120) or the window bounds are changed.

Most of the advice I have found is all about using scene.itemsBoundingRect()- which I believe I am using correctly.

You can see just how tiny the graphic is being drawn in the screenshot.

[image: very tiny graphic]

```py
from itertools import product
from math import ceil
from random import choices
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPointF


class Art:
    normal = 100
    w_off = 2
    line = normal / 2
    t_l = QPointF(-line + w_off, -line + w_off)
    t_r = QPointF(+line - w_off, -line + w_off)
    b_r = QPointF(+line - w_off, +line - w_off)
    b_l = QPointF(-line + w_off, +line - w_off)

    @staticmethod
    def _poly(edges):
        pt = [Art.t_r, Art.b_r, Art.b_l, Art.t_l]
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(Art.t_l)
        for i in range(4):
            path.lineTo(pt[i]) if edges[i] else path.moveTo(pt[i])
        return path

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1
        self.z = 1
        self.cells = {}
        self.scenes = []
        self.polygons = {x: self._poly(x) for x in product((False, True), repeat=4)}

    def reset(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.cells = {tuple((ix, iy, iz)): tuple(choices([True, False], k=4))
                      for ix in range(self.x)
                      for iy in range(self.y)
                      for iz in range(self.z)
                      }
        for scene in self.scenes:
            scene.clear()

    def draw(self):
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin)
        for x, y, z in self.cells:
            cx1 = x * Art.normal
            cy1 = y * Art.normal
            shape = self.polygons[self.cells[x, y, z]]
            self.scenes[z].addPath(shape.translated(QPointF(cx1, cy1)), pen)


class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    """
    Is the main application window, which is made of two parts:
    One one side is the pane of tabs which display the maze
    On the other are the configurable values of the maze (levels)
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.pane = None
        self.form = None
        self.horizontal_layout = None
        super().__init__()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.pane.resize()
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def setup(self):
        self.pane = Pane(self)
        self.form = Form(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Configure")
        self.setObjectName("Dialog")
        size_policy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        size_policy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        size_policy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        size_policy.setHeightForWidth(self.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.setSizePolicy(size_policy)
        self.horizontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontal_layout.setObjectName("horizontal_layout")
        self.pane.setup(self.horizontal_layout)
        self.form.setup(self.horizontal_layout)
        self.pane.connect_form(self.form)


class Pane:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent    # This is the widget.
        self.layout = None      # This is the parent's layout.
        self.form = None        # This is the form used to control things.
        self.tab_widget = None  # This is the tab widget, which can be fully replaced.
        # Everything below are default values.
        self.offset = 12
        self.demi = self.offset // 2
        self.tmp_idx = 0
        self.levels = 4
        self.width = 3
        self.height = 3
        self.cell_size = 100
        self.art = None
        self.level_tabs = []
        self.level_gx = []

    def setup(self, parent_layout):
        self.layout = parent_layout
        self.art = Art()
        tab_widget_dim = QRect(0, 0, 360, 380)  # This is the size of the initial tab_widget
        self.set_tab_widget(tab_widget_dim)

    def connect_form(self, form):
        self.form = form
        self.form.set_values({'Size': self.cell_size, 'Levels': self.levels})
        self.form.set_listen({'Size': self.resize, 'Levels': self.re_depth})

    def make_tab_widget(self):
        self.tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.parent)
        self.tab_widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(360, 380))
        self.tab_widget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tab_widget.setObjectName("tab_widget")

    def reset_tab_widget(self):
        self.tmp_idx = 0
        prev_widget = self.tab_widget
        self.make_tab_widget()
        if prev_widget:
            self.tmp_idx = prev_widget.currentIndex()
            self.parent.horizontal_layout.replaceWidget(prev_widget, self.tab_widget)
            prev_widget.clear()
            prev_widget.close()
        else:
            self.parent.horizontal_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)
        if self.art:
            for lt in self.level_tabs:
                lt.close()
            self.level_tabs = []
            for gx in self.level_gx:
                gx.close()
            self.level_gx = []
            self.art.scenes = []

    def adjust_gx(self, gv, scene, frame):
        # Resize the graphics port to fit the outer frame. (GUI pixels)
        gv.resize(frame.width(), frame.height())
        # Seems to make no difference.
        boundary = scene.itemsBoundingRect()
        gv.fitInView(boundary, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        scene.setSceneRect(boundary)
        # Also tried the below...
        # gv.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def set_tab_widget(self, tab_widget_dim):
        self.reset_tab_widget()  # initialises / replaces a QTabWidget into the horizontal_layout
        for level in range(self.levels):
            tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            tab.setObjectName(f"T{level}")
            self.tab_widget.addTab(tab, f"{level + 1}")
            self.level_tabs.append(tab)
            scene = QGraphicsScene()
            self.art.scenes.append(scene)
            tab.resize(tab_widget_dim.width(), tab_widget_dim.height())
            gv = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene, tab)
            gv.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            gv.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            gv.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(340, 340))
            gv.setObjectName(f"Gx{level}")
            self.level_gx.append(gv)
            # self.adjust_gx(gv, scene, tab_widget_dim)
        self.art.reset(self.width, self.height, self.levels)
        self.art.draw()
        for idx in range(self.levels):
            self.adjust_gx(self.level_gx[idx], self.art.scenes[idx], tab_widget_dim)
        self.tab_widget.setCurrentIndex(self.tmp_idx % self.levels)

    def resize(self):
        if self.tab_widget:
            self.tab_widget.hide()
            idx = self.tab_widget.currentIndex()
            dt = QRect(self.level_tabs[idx].frameGeometry())
            self.cell_size = self.form.get_value('Size')
            self.width = ceil((dt.width() - self.offset) // self.cell_size)
            self.height = ceil((dt.height() - self.offset) // self.cell_size)
            self.form.set_texts({'Width': f"{self.width}", 'Height': f"{self.height}"})
            self.set_tab_widget(dt)
            self.tab_widget.show()
            self.parent.update()

    def re_depth(self):
        self.levels = self.form.get_value('Levels')
        self.resize()


class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.form = None
        self.label_text = ('Levels', 'Size', 'Width', 'Height')
        self.minimums = (1, 16)
        self.maximums = (20, 320)
        self.labels = []
        self.fields = {}
        super().__init__(self.parent)

    def setup(self, parent_layout):
        self.form = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        self.form.setObjectName("form")
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(160, 200))
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(160, 200))

        # Create the fields within the form layout
        for field in range(4):
            if field < 2:
                ui = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self)
                ui.setMinimum(self.minimums[field])
                ui.setMaximum(self.maximums[field])
                ui.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 0))
                ui.setObjectName(f"f_{field}")
            else:
                ui = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
                ui.setObjectName(f"f_{field}")
                ui.setText(f"{0}")
            self.form.setWidget(field + 1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, ui)
            self.fields[self.label_text[field]] = ui
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            label.setObjectName(f"label_{field}")
            label.setText(self.label_text[field])
            self.form.setWidget(field + 1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, label)
            self.labels.append(label)
        parent_layout.addWidget(self)

    def get_value(self, name):
        return self.fields[name].value()

    def set_values(self, config):
        for k in config.keys():
            self.fields[k].setValue(config[k])

    def set_texts(self, config):
        for k in config.keys():
            self.fields[k].setText(config[k])

    def set_listen(self, config):
        for k in config.keys():
            self.fields[k].valueChanged.connect(config[k])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = MyDialog()
    dialog.setup()
    dialog.show()
    result = app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to do the fitview a moment later because for efficiency reasons Qt does not immediately update the properties:

```py
# ...
self.art.reset(self.width, self.height, self.levels)
self.art.draw()

def adjust():
    for idx in range(self.levels):
        self.adjust_gx(self.level_gx[idx], self.art.scenes[idx], tab_widget_dim)

QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, adjust)

self.tab_widget.setCurrentIndex(self.tmp_idx % self.levels)
# ...
```

Comment: That seems to work! I probably need to play around with it a bit - do you have a link to any documentation that explains what is going on?

Comment: @Konchog I have not found anything documented but that is what I understood after analyzing the Qt source code